# Cannot get document.getElementById() to find my textarea

Tags: javascript, cakephp

Maybe I've been working on my site for to long, but I can't get the following to work.  I am having my textarea fire an onkeyup() event called limiter which is supposed to check the textarea and limit the text in the box, while updated another readonly input field that shows the amount of characters left.

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = "500";
function limiter(){
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment");
    var form = this.parent;
    var tex = comment.value;
    var len = tex.length;
    if(len > count){
        tex = tex.substring(0,count);
        comment.value =tex;
        return false;
    }
    form.limit.value = count-len;
}
</script>
```

The form looks like this:

```
<form id="add-course-rating" method="post" action="/course_ratings/add/8/3/5/3" 
accept-  charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" 
name="_method"    value="POST" />


    //Other inputs here

    <div id="comment-name" style="margin-top:10px">
    <div id="comment-name-text">
    <b>Comments</b><br />
    Please leave any comments that you think will help anyone else.
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
    .rating-form-box textarea {
        -moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="rating-form-box">
             <textarea name="data[CourseRatings][comment]" id="comment" 
                 onkeyup="limiter()" cols="115" rows="5" ></textarea>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                     document.write("<input type=text name=limit size=4 
                     readonly value="+count+">");
                 </script>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Add Rating" style="float: right;">
</form>
```

If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Sorry this was another attempt, will fix now

Comment: Put the scripts after </form> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work for your? [Example Link](http://jsbin.com/olula4/2)

EDIT:
You should pass the element instance with the function call `onkeyup="limiter(this)"` this way in your function you'll have a reference to the object that called this function, now your function will be something like:

```
function limiter(a) {
    var comment = a;
    var form = document.getElementById('add-course-rating');
    var tex = comment.value;
    var len = tex.length;
    if (len > count) {
        tex = tex.substring(0, count);
        comment.value = tex;
        return false;
    }
    form.limit.value = count - len;
}
```

Also no need to create element dynamically if you don't really need that! so just set the value of the readonly with Javascript:

```
<input type="text" name="limit" id="limit" size="4" readonly value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var limit = document.getElementById('limit');
  limit.value = count;
</script>
```

And you are good to go!

Comment: @Slruh - great, please keep in mind @David's comments about dealing with `this` and `parent` not to confused with `parentNode`...

Comment: Why the down vote guys? please leave the reason to know what went wrong here..!!!

Comment: @ifaour I haven't looked into your code on that page, but I think the problem stems from the fact that you just posted a link to an external jsbin without providing a description for what you did. This isn't in the spirit of StackOverflow because if somebody comes across this post in the future, they might encounter a dead link or they might be confused by what you did (I know I am without seeing a description). Also...I didn't downvote your answer, just explaining why others probably did.

Comment: @treeface - +1, you are definitely right about your point. the thing is, most of my active time on SO is at midnight and sometimes it would actually harder for me to describe the solutions from the solutions themselves!! since English isn't my native language and I would be so tired! :-)

Comment: @ifaour No worries, it's completely understandable. But now that you've written that nice description, I understand more what this whole question was about. I think you write English much better than you give yourself credit for ;-]. Also you just earned an upvote.

Comment: @treeface - hope you are right (about the _English_ bit), and thanks for the upvote! :-)

Comment: @ifaour Trust me...I've spent a lot of my life training native foreign language speakers and learning foreign languages. Your command of English syntax, while not perfect, is a far cry better than many native English speakers. If I hadn't looked at your user profile, I might even have been fooled. Your core ability appears to be solid...it just needs some work around the edges.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
onkeyup="limiter()"
```

Since you aren't calling `limiter` in the context of an object, you are calling `window.limiter`.

```
var form = this.parent;
```

So `this` is `window` and `form` is `window.parent`, which is the same as `window` (unless the document is loaded in a frame).

You want to make `this` the form control. Do this using [event binding](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) in [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

(And don't use an `input` as an element solely for displaying *output*, it does not make sense. You probably want to use a label associated with the textarea … and to use another label for `<b>Comments</b><br />Please leave any comments that you think will help anyone else.`)